# How to choose a specific element in a list I defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphene-python

I wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np


a=0.142
c1=np.array([0,0])
c2=np.array([a,0]) #[nm]
a1= np.array([3/2*a,3**0.5/2*a])
a2= np.array([3/2*a,-3**0.5/2*a])

my_list = [] 
def Rnm_1():
    for n in range(10):
        for m in range(10):
            Rnm_1= c1 + (n*a1+m*a2)
            my_list.append(Rnm_1)
    return my_list
```

`Rnm_1()` here gives multiple arrays, how can I access each and every "first term" from all the arrays?
I want to calculate the distance and I need to use **all** the x and y values that are stored in those arrays.
Thank you if helped.

### Summary:

**I want to find out how the can I access the first value of every array.**

Comment: Don't use same name for function and variable, it might cause you a lot of problems later on.

Comment: `[arr[0] for arr in my_list]`

Comment: As a side note: Your code is a bit hard to head due to placement of the spaces. You might to look into [PEP 8 styling guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations)

Answer (score 0):

1-dimensional arrays can be [index like python lists](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html):

```py
import numpy as np

a = 0.142
c1 = np.array([0, 0])
c2 = np.array([a, 0]) #[nm]
a1 = np.array([3/2*a, 3**0.5/2*a])
a2 = np.array([3/2*a, -3**0.5/2*a])

def Rnm_1():
    my_list = [] 
    for n in range(10):
        for m in range(10):
            Rnm_1 = c1 + (n*a1+m*a2)
            my_list.append(Rnm_1)
    return my_list

my_arrays = Rnm_1()

for arr in my_arrays:
    first_item = arr[0]
    print(f"first item of array {arr}: {first_item}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use NumPy all the way through:

```py
a = 0.142
c1 = np.array([0, 0])
c2 = np.array([a, 0])
a1 = np.array([3/2 * a, 3**0.5 / 2 * a])
a2 = np.array([3/2 * a, -3**0.5 / 2 * a])

def Rnm_1(c1, a1, a2):
    r = np.arange(10)
    return c1 + np.outer(np.repeat(r, 10), a1) + np.outer(np.tile(r, 10), a2)

arr = Rnm_1(c1, a1, a2)
print(arr[:, 0])
```

`arr[:, 0]` will give you the first column of `arr`, which seems to be what you want. If you really need the arrays (rows) in a list, then do `my_list = list(arr)`.